# Symfony2, EntityManager::getRepository(Namespace\To\Some\Class::class или '**Bundle:Entity')

Tags: php, классы, symfony2

В документации Symfony2 говориться, что в методе EntityManager::**getRepository** в качестве аргумента нужно указывать строковый литерал в формате **'SomeBundle:EntityName'**

Однако этот метод нормально принимает и литерал в стандартном виде полного имени класса.

Как известно, любой класс php поддерживает "волшебный" **метод ::class**, возвращающий это самое полное имя.

Мне кажется, правильнее использовать именно класс и его волшебный метод.
Так и рефакторинг проводить проще, и переход к классу в IDE можно сделать.

Как в итоге "правильно" и удобнее?

Comment: По имени бандла.

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить об IDE, то если вы используете PHPStorm + Symfony2 плагин, то проблем с рефакторингов у вас не будет.

В принцип вы можете использовать метод `Entity::class` если вам удобнее, но имейте ввиду, что при использовании репозиториев как сервисы, вы не сможете использовать такую конструкцию в `services.yml`, и там придеться либо вставлять полное имя класса, либо короткое название `BlogBundle:EntityName`.

Выберите для себя подходящий способ. Но если вы пишите с использованием фреймворка `symfony2`, лучше использовать его "нативные" (`BundleName:EntityName`) способы.